How to Use koffi with Struct Pointers
#pragma pack(1)
struct EnvInfo
{
DWORD dwSize; 
WCHAR wszAppId[128]; 
ULONGLONG u64Qid; 
};

extern "C" int __stdcall SDK360_Init(const EnvInfo* pEnvInfo);

this c++ code
const envInfo = koffi.pack('envInfo', {
    dwSize: 'uint32',
    wszAppId: koffi.array('char16', 128),
    u64Qid: 'uint64'
});

const arr = 'xtI7nxn';
const utf16Buffer = new Uint16Array(128); 
arr.forEach((char, index) => {
    utf16Buffer[index] = char.charCodeAt(0);
});

envInfo.dwSize = koffi.sizeof(envInfo);
envInfo.wszAppId = utf16Buffer;
envInfo.u64Qid = 3269309681;

const sdk360 = koffi.load(dynamicLib);
const SDK360_Init = sdk360.func('SDK360_Init', 'int', [koffi.pointer(envInfo)]); 

const result = SDK360_Init(envInfo);

I tried to do this, but I get an error, I don't know what's wrong.
TypeError: Unexpected Type value, expected envInfo *

Isn't this a matter of passing [envInfo]?

Thank you, my argument was passed wrong, envInfo just defined the type, I took it as the value

If I understand the Koffi documentation correctly you are allowed to assign to members of a struct declaration (as it is the only way to make anonymous structs).
